# Calling delete on address of variable

Tags: c++, runtime-error, stack-overflow, delete-operator

Why can I do:

```
int i = *(new int (5));
```

and successfuly use `i` after it,

but when I'm trying:

```
delete &i;
```

I get a run time error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5ddccaf7 (msvcr100d.dll) in Test.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

If `i` was a reference:

```
int & i = *(new int (5));
```

, all this (including `delete`) works fine.

I know, that it's no good to keep allocated memory handler in something other than pointer and `*(new ...)` is awful, but I'm just wondering, why `new` works good, but `delete` fails.

//Below are just my guesses about the reason of such behavior:

Is it because module which executes program (it's probably not "compiler", because of there is **run time** already) when it encounters with `delete`, it searches for some information like length of data pointing by `&i` (in some internal array of such information about all pointers) and don't find it or interpretes some trash data as this information? (I suppose, pointers and references have it, but variables don't)

Comment: Pointers and references are not the same. You cannot delete a reference.

Comment: You understand `int i = *(new int (5));` is an instant-memory-leak, right?

Comment: Because when you do `int i = *(new int (5));`, the original pointer to `*(new int(5))` is lost and `i` is initialized to the value of this expression, which is 5. `i` and `new int(5)` are not the same locations, though, which is why you can't `delete &i`.

Comment: @Ben, I suppose, for references works `delete &i;` (not deleting reference, but the data, it's points to)
At least, I haven't errors on this line.

Comment: @user3241228 that line is valid. You cannot delete a reference. You *can* delete something *referenced* if it was dynamically allocated, which is what your second example does. And though it is rarely done, it is perfectly legal to do so. Do not think of it as deleting a reference; remember address-of applied to a reference returns *the address of the referenced* (the "ed" in that word is important).

Comment: @WhozCraig, to be honest, I didn't, until the Daniel Kamil Kozar's comment (Thanks, Daniel)

Comment: @Ben you can delete the address of a reference. (Whether this is UB or not depends on what the reference was bound to)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, can you give a couple of examples when it causes UB and when doesn't? Thank you.

Comment: @user3241228 `delete` can only be called on the same pointer as was `new`'d , or that pointer converted to a base class which has virtual destructor. Other cases are UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original version does not assign `i` to an address. It allocates a new int on the heap and initializes its value to 5, then copies that value into `i` which is on the stack. The memory that you allocated (`new`'ed) is inaccessible and gets leaked.

The reference version works because `i` refers to the otherwise-anonymous `new`'ed memory. Hence `&i` gives the heap address. In your first version, `&i` gives the address of the stack variable, not the heap memory, and deleting stack memory is bad news.

Answer (score 4):

You get a run-time error because the address of `i` is not the same as the address returned by the operator `new`. Once you dereference the result of `new`, you make a *copy* of the value. That copy is then placed into variable `i`, which has an address in automatic storage, which cannot be passed to `delete` legally without triggering undefined behavior.

When you make a reference, however, you do not make a copy: the result of `new` becomes referenced through a variable `i` of type "reference to `int`". Hence, the reference has the same address as has been returned by `operator new`,  so the code that uses the reference works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
int i = *(new int (5));
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int* p = new int(5);
int i = *p;
```

The address of `i` (which you are trying to `delete`) is not the address of the allocated memory.

In mathematical notation, `&x == &y` implies `x == y`, but `x == y`does not imply `&x == &y`.